# How to compute $Cov(\hat{Y}, Y)$ in R?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning

Given $\hat{Y}$ and $Y$, is there a way to compute the covariance matrix using R?
For OLS regression, $Cov(\hat{Y}, Y) = \sigma^2 H$, where $H = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$.
But when I do

```
cov(Y_hat, Y)
```

It only returns a single value. I'm wondering if there's a function in R that can compute the matrix (without directly calculating the hat matrix)?

Comment: You can compute $\mathbf H$ by using `X%*%solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)`. Then you can compute your desired matrix if you know $\sigma^2.$

Comment: Thanks! But I'm wondering if there's a way to compute it without computing the Hat matrix directly (I'm doing elastic net and using bootstrap to find its effective degrees of freedom, and since there's no closed-form expression for the estimated coefficient, there's no way to compute the covariance matrix like the hat matrix without using R)

Comment: This (interesting) question might get more attention if it is edited to focus on the statistics of computing the covariance matrix in an elastic net regression, rather than the programming in particular software.